# IOS Creating Utility Class For NSURL

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I have a project I am working on that has a number of different news feeds and announcement boards that displays post from various sources.  Currently I have the code for the like, delete and flag buttons in methods contained in each class file for the views that display the feeds.  I have been trying to craft a utility class that allows me to place the code for the three functionalities listed above in one object to be used throughout the project.  I have done the exact same type of thing in C++ or Java, but am having issues reproducing it in objective-c.  The like, delete and flag buttons use the NSURL libraries to interact with the web service.  Bellow is an example of one of the methods I am trying to implement in the utility class, and is the code used to be implemented in the like buttons:

```
+ (void)btnLikeAction:(UIButton *)btnLike userIdString:(NSString *)userId contentSource:(NSString *)sourceId cellUsed:(NewsfeedCell *)cell dataForCell:(Post *)post
{
    BOOL hasLiked = post.hasLiked;
    UILabel *likeLabel = cell.likeCount;
    NSString *pId = post.postId;

    if (hasLiked)
    {
        [btnLike setEnabled:NO];

        NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://192.155.94.183/api/v1/likes/unlike/%@/%@/%@/", sourceId, pId, userId];

        NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30.0];

        NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        [connection start];

        int localCount = [likeLabel.text intValue];
        localCount--;
        likeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", localCount];
        post.likeCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", localCount];
        post.hasLiked = NO;

        [btnLike setEnabled:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        [btnLike setEnabled:NO];

        NSError *err = nil;
        NSDictionary *likeData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  userId, @"user_id",
                                  pId, @"source_id",
                                  sourceId, @"source",
                                  nil];

        NSData *JSONLike = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:likeData options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&err];
        NSString *url = @"http://192.155.94.183/api/v1/likes.json";

        NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL
                                                               cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                           timeoutInterval:30.0];

        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [JSONLike length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setHTTPBody:JSONLike];

        NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        [connection start];

        int localCount = [likeLabel.text intValue];
        localCount++;
        likeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", localCount];
        post.likeCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", localCount];
        post.hasLiked = YES;

        [btnLike setEnabled:YES];
    }
}
```

This code uses a web service to update the number of likes for a specific piece of content.  It works when the method is placed into the individual ViewController class files, but when I try to make a utility class with the individual methods I run into issues with the `didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge`, `didReceiveResponse`, `didReceiveData` and `connectionDidFinishLoading` methods not being called.  Originally, I assumed that the delegate methods would be called in the file that that the utility methods were called in.  But that was not the case.  When I implemented the method definitions in the actual utility class, the methods still weren't called.  I did some research on the topic and looked into [this article](http://m-hewedy.blogspot.ca/2011/10/centralize-your-nsurlconnection-code.html) but found I was unable to find substantial resources that helped my specific situation.  How do I set up my utility class?  I can post the full code of the utility if needed.

Comment: Does your custom class conform to NSURLConnectionDelegate?

Comment: Since you are setting the NSURLConnection delegate as "self" from an static method, you are passing your custom class as delegate instead of passing an instance of your custom class. Convert your class method to an instance method and it should work.

Comment: No I don't think so, I'm currently reading the NSURL documentation [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  How do I make it conform to NSURLConnectionDelegate? @serrrgi

Comment: @ScottOBot: serrrgi *is* right. Alternatively, you can use the `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` method which does not use a delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @serrrgi already said, the problem is that `btnLikeAction:...` is a *class method*, so that `self` is the class itself. You have the following options:

- Make all delegate methods class methods, e.g.

  ```
  + (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
  {
      NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse");
  }
  ```
- Create an *instance* of your Utility class and use that as delegate:

  ```
  YourClass *u = [[self alloc] init];
  NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:u];
  ```
- Use `sendAsynchronousRequest:...`, which does not need a delegate:

  ```
  [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
      if (data != nil) {
          NSLog(@"success");
      } else {
          NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
      }
  }];
  ```

Comment: I'm implementing the solution above will let you know if I am successful

Comment: Worked with flag and delete as well! Thanks so much man! @Martin R